# Node Async.auto Callback is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, async.js

I've got a problem with my nodejs script and async library.
Ive got an async.auto with 2 parts. First part ok, in second part I've got another async.auto with 2 parts which are nearly the same, some changes in sql queries and arrays. But the first part here works fine, the second one the zutKopf stops with failure that the callback function cbzutk is not a function. Ive tried to fixed it somedays but can't find out the failure because its written like the first part zubKopf.

Hopefully u can help me.

Greets

```
    async.auto({
    one: function(cbone){
        db.getConnection(function(err, dbs){
            dbs.query("insert into rezepte (kat_id, rez_name, rez_desc, rez_img) values(?,?,?,?)",[RezeptComp.rezept.kat_id,RezeptComp.rezept.rez_name,RezeptComp.rezept.rez_desc,RezeptComp.rezept.rez_img],function(err, rows) {
                if (err) {
                    cbone(err);
                    return;
                }
                console.log('query Rezept');
                rezeptId = rows.insertId;
                RezeptComp.rezept.rez_id = rows.insertId;
                dbs.release();
                cbone(null);
            });
        });
    },
    two: ['one', function(cbtwo){
            async.auto({
                zubKopf: function(cbzubk){
                    async.eachSeries(RezeptComp.zubereitung, function(data,next){
                        db.getConnection(function(err,dbzubk){
                            dbzubk.query("insert into zubereitungKopf (rez_id, zubk_text) values("+ rezeptId +",'"+ data.zubk_text +"')",function(err, rows) {
                                if (err) {
                                    cbtwo(err);
                                    return;
                                }
                                console.log('query zubk');
                                zubkId = rows.insertId;
                                RezeptComp.zubereitung[zubkd].zubk_id = zubkId;
                                dbzubk.release();
                                async.eachSeries(data.zubp, function(data2,next2){
                                    db.getConnection(function(err,dbzubp){
                                        dbzubp.query("insert into zubereitungPos (zubk_id, zubp_text) values("+ zubkId +",'"+ data2.zubp_text +"')",function(err, rows) {
                                            if (err) {
                                                cbtwo(err);
                                                return;
                                            }
                                            console.log('query zubp');
                                            zubpId = rows.insertId;
                                            RezeptComp.zubereitung[zubkd].zubp[zubpd].zubp_id = zubpId;
                                            dbzubp.release();
                                            zubpd = zubpd + 1;
                                            next2(null);
                                        });
                                    });
                                }, function(err, results){
                                    zubkd = zubkd + 1;
                                    zubpd = 0;
                                    next(null);
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    }, function(err, results){
                        cbzubk(null);
                    });  
                },
                zutKopf: ['zubKopf', function(cbzutk){
                    async.eachSeries(RezeptComp.zutaten, function(data3,next3){
                        db.getConnection(function(err,dbzutk){
                            dbzutk.query("insert into zutatenKopf (rez_id, zutk_text) values("+ rezeptId +",'"+ data3.zutk_text +"')",function(err, rows) {
                                if (err) {
                                    cbzutk(err);
                                    return;
                                }
                                console.log('query zutk');
                                zutkId = rows.insertId;
                                RezeptComp.zutaten[zutkd].zutk_id = zutkId;
                                dbzutk.release();
                                async.eachSeries(data3.zutp, function(data4,next4){
                                    db.getConnection(function(err,dbzutp){
                                        dbzutp.query("insert into zutatenPos (zutk_id, zutp_text) values("+ zutkId +",'"+ data4.zutp_text +"')",function(err, rows) {
                                            if (err) {
                                                cbzutk(err);
                                                return;
                                            }
                                            console.log('query zutp');
                                            zutpId = rows.insertId;
                                            RezeptComp.zutaten[zutkd].zutp[zutpd].zutp_id = zutpId;
                                            dbzutp.release();
                                            zutpd = zutpd + 1;
                                            next4(null);
                                        });
                                    });
                                }, function(err, results){
                                    zutkd = zutkd + 1;
                                    zutpd = 0;
                                    next3(null);
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    }, function(err, results){
                        cbzutk(null);
                    });    
                }],
                final: ['zubKopf', 'zutKopf', function(error, results){
                    cbtwo(null);
                }]
            }); 
    }],
    final: ['one', 'two', function(error, results){
        callback(RezepComp);
    }]
});
```

Comment: I didn't have time to really look into this, but the first thing I would try is looking at all callers of `zutKopf` and confirming that an actual `function()` is passed in to the parameter list. Maybe you are accidentally passing in string for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In async.auto depending functions receive as first a parameter from the previous function and then   you can define the callback in the functionheader like `two: ['one', function(parameter, callback)` instead of `two: ['one', function(callback)`.